# Can't login to SKYPE SDK samples

Tags: skype, skype-for-business

I am trying to run the web samples distributed with the new SKYPE SDK. I don't have an on premise Lync server so I am using the Domain and Token login provided at the site.

```
Domain=metio.net
Token= Bearer cwt=AAEBHAEFAAAAAAAFFQAAAKuuXmvzGAIi1fxkeZUMAACBEFGt0YtqM3BVrxhrtkQkKFqCAoCDgyBiUaV6fPrpGdHv_Vl5hHoss0owQitMzh9xvY5tjoKyLoYIslm_avRm0ggNEPafGCkKskFVn6NvOvBYlbY
```

But the login never completes. The busy circle just spins forever. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: I am unable to understand your question ...please if you elaborate it then I can help you...ok

Comment: Which example are you doing? We need to know more about your code and your configuration? This is a Login example with javascript https://github.com/tomorgan/SkypeWebSDKSamples/blob/gh-pages/Login/Getting%20Logged%20In/index.htm Are you follow this Server Prerequisites?  http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/04/learn-skype-web-api-day-2-server-prerequisites/

Comment: Do you have Skype for Businness Plan? According to the article below the  the Skype Web SDK is only for Skype for Business, not Skype Consumer. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2456ef60-b37f-44d7-b1ef-4cb46b89fc6a/regular-skype?forum=SkypeWebSDK

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- JQuery. Skype Web SDK requires JQuery to work. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap layouts and themes. Totally optional, but it makes the examples look much nicer -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/metro/css/metro-bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- This is the Skype for Web SDK -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//swx.cdn.skype.com/shared/v/1.1.23.0/SkypeBootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<!-- Skype for Web API Code by Tom Morgan | thoughtstuff.co.uk -->
<!-- This is one of a number of examples showing how to use the Skype for Web API. The full list is at skypewebsdk.com -->
<!-- Disclaimer: use at your own risk. -->
<div class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Email">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<button class="btn btn-default" id="btnLogIn">Log in</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<!-- This is not needed for the samples to run, but adds standard headers and footers to the samples, to display title, instructions, about etc.
If you're taking this code and using it yourself, you can remove this.-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/layoutcodesample-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- These variables are only needed for laying out the code sample, they are not part of the sample code. -->
var pageTitle = "Getting Logged In";
var blogPostLocation = "http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/04/learn-skype-web-sdk-day-1-logging-in/";
var githubLocation = "https://github.com/tomorgan/SkypeWebSDKSamples/blob/gh-pages/Login/Getting%20Logged%20In/index.htm";
var client;
$(function () {
'use strict';
Skype.initialize({
apiKey: 'SWX-BUILD-SDK',
}, function (api) {
client = new api.application();
}, function (err) {
alert('some error occurred: ' + err);
});
$('#btnLogIn').click(function () {
// start signing in
client.signInManager.signIn({
username: $('#username').val(),
password: $('#password').val()
}).then(function () {
//log in worked!
alert('Logged in!');
}, function (error) {
//Something went wrong.
alert(error);
});
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code didn't solve my problem (see below) but was also helpful. Thanks for the attention and help sir.

Comment: @YumYumYum What didn't worked. Can you explain? As you might see that it help other people. let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @JafferWilson: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40080892/285594 please see this question where i used exactly your way, but it keeps failing.

Comment: Please everyone check the following reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/downloadrunsamples It will help.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem and this is how it got solved:

1. Host the SDK samples (or the project) on the Local IIS (not IIS Express).
2. This way you can access the site with the machine IP (ex. http://10.100.101.185/ or http://10.100.101.185/sdksamples/) and not http://localhost/.
3. Now add this IP to the trusted connections by Lync server as described here in this article (Step 3).

You should now be able to complete the sign in process.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

I was going through the Skype samples on their website, but I couldn't get those sample to work.  I was using the sample listed above where i typed in metio.net and the oauth token.  The problem I was running into is that I was using these samples out from within my work network.  There must be some sort of firewall or other issue that prevented the sample form working because once I tried it from my home computer it worked fine.