# Impossible to use this SDK is it possible that its unstable SDK?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

According to the documentation, I followed everything correctly, but I keep getting this following error:

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Skype Web SDK app</title>
  <script src="https://swx.cdn.skype.com/shared/v/1.2.15/SkypeBootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    Skype.initialize({ apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255' }, api => {
      var app = new api.application;
      app.signInManager.signIn ({
        username: 'sdfsfsfdsfsdf', //USE VALID username
        password: 'xxx'  // USE VALID password
      }).then(() => {
        console.log("signed in as", app.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.displayName());
      }, err => {
        console.log("cannot sign in", err);
      });
    }, err => {
      console.log("cannot load the sdk package", err);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does the link points to gmail.com ? You have to provide the Lync Server address for discovery of Lync service

Comment: what are you using ? You are trying to login into a Skype for Business server. Where is the server hosted? You have to specify the domain of the Skype for Business server you are connecting to.

Comment: You have 2 options. Either you can setup a Skype for Business Server in your organisation. If your organisation uses Lync then you can connect directly to that. If you dont have anything in your organisation, you can use the Skype for Business Online servers provided by Microsoft. But for that you would need 2 things. An Office 365 account with which you would login into Skype for Business online. And an Azure Subscription which would have an Azure Active directory required to register your application. Let me know which option are you using or planning to use. Then I can help you better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843684/developing-ucwa-online-for-ios-application/39871016#39871016

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384270/display-the-user-presence-status-using-skype-web-sdk-or-ucwa-in-uwp-app/39401560#39401560

Comment: Refer the above 2 links. You need an app that would connect to Skype For Business and then you need to register that app in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to sign in with a gmail account into Skype for Business. This isn't supported.